# Calculate Line Height Based on Adjacent Elements

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I've come across a tricky Bootstrap/JavaScript/CSS problem. I'd like the headers in the adjacent thumbnails pictured below to all take up the same amount of space. By default, the `h3` tags all have a line height of 26px.

For the one header whose text hasn't wrapped to a second line, I can manually set its line-height to `52px` to achieve the desired effect.

[image: Sized correctly]

But when I resize the window, things fall out of place again.

[image: Screwed up]

Is there a way to calculate the max height of the 4 elements, and then set the line-height appropriately in the element(s) where the text hasn't wrapped yet?

Comment: Can you post the code? Have you tried flexbox?

Comment: I don't see flebox helping here (given that the boxes are grouped by content). However, grid layout may actually work.

Comment: @ZimSystem I'm using flexbox to make the thumbnails all the same height currently, could I perhaps set `.thumbnail .h3 { height: 40% }` so that the header always takes up the same portion of the thumbnail? Will post code momentarily.

Comment: @Christoph can you elaborate further? Having never used grid before, it's slightly confusing.

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is actually working in your scenario. The trick is to define the thumnails themselves as flexboxes again. Then you can define `flex-grow` on your `h3` elements to always fill the entire remaining space (while the other elements have `flex-grow=0`). See the following example code (use "full page" to easily adjust the width of the items):

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 160px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h3 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/*decoration*/
main {padding: 5px;background: #ccc; }section { background: #fff;border-radius: 3px; margin: 5px;padding: 10px;} h3 { margin: 0 0 20px;}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <h3> OD Approval </h3>
    <div> In Progress </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3> Supervisor Approval </h3>
    <div> In Progress </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3> HR Approval </h3>
    <div> In Progress </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3> Grades and Receipts (longer text to wrap)</h3>
    <div> In Progress </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

This solution doesn't even need any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 flexbox will work. Here's an example with cards..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card card-block h-100 text-center">
                <div class="h-75 d-flex justify-content-center py-2 bg-info rounded">
                    <h3 class="my-auto">Snippets</h3>
                </div>
                <h1>313</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card card-block h-100 text-center">
                <div class="h-75 d-flex justify-content-center py-2 bg-info rounded">
                    <h3 class="my-auto">Templates and Themes</h3>
                </div>
                <h1>48</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card card-block h-100 text-center">
                <div class="h-75 d-flex justify-content-center py-2 bg-info rounded">
                    <h3 class="my-auto">Example Code</h3>
                </div>
                <h1>982</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="card card-block h-100 text-center">
                <div class="h-75 d-flex justify-content-center py-2 bg-info rounded">
                    <h3 class="my-auto">More Downloads</h3>
                </div>
                <h1>412</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/FDEt2gK20L

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around, I was able to find a combination that works. The biggest key to resolving the issue was to set `.panel-body {height: 100%}`

HTML:

```
<Row id="workflow-display-hor">
      <Col sm={3} className="first">
        <Panel>
          <h3 style={{ color: config.OD.textColor }}>
            OD Approval
          </h3>
          <p style={{ color: config.OD.textColor }} className="status-p">
            {config.OD.status}
          </p>
          <p className="verify-circle">
            <MdCheckCircle style={{ verticalAlign: 'text-bottom', color: config.OD.color }} size={25} />
          </p>
        </Panel>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={3}>
        <Panel>
          <h3 style={{ color: config.Super.textColor }}>
            Supervisor Approval
          </h3>
          <p style={{ color: config.Super.textColor }} className="status-p">
            {config.Super.status}
          </p>
          <p className="verify-circle">
            <MdCheckCircle style={{verticalAlign: 'text-bottom', color: config.Super.color }} size={25} />
          </p>
        </Panel>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={3}>
        <Panel>
          <h3 style={{ color: config.HR.textColor }}>
            HR Approval
          </h3>
          <p style={{ color: config.HR.textColor }} className="status-p">
            {config.HR.status}
          </p>
          <p className="verify-circle">
            <MdCheckCircle style={{verticalAlign: 'text-bottom', color: config.HR.color }} size={25} />
          </p>
        </Panel>
      </Col>
      <Col sm={3} className="last">
        <Panel>
          <h3 style={{ color: config.GR.textColor }}>
            Grades & Receipts
          </h3>
          <p style={{ color: config.GR.textColor }} className="status-p">
            {config.GR.status}
          </p>
          <p className="verify-circle">
            <MdCheckCircle style={{verticalAlign: 'text-bottom', color: config.GR.color }} size={25} />
          </p>
        </Panel>
      </Col>
    </Row>
```

CSS:

```
#workflow-display-hor.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#workflow-display-hor .panel {
  height: 95%;
}

#workflow-display-hor .panel > .panel-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
#workflow-display-hor .status-p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#workflow-display-hor .panel h3 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Result:

[image: Resolved]